# how to serialise / de-serialise a Generic List of Properties?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an Entity Component System whereby each entity is defined by a series of components. A Component being a peice of data derived from a base Component Object
The application contains a list of 1000's of Entities, which i need to serialise.

i.e.

```
public class Entity{
    public Guid ID{get;set;}
    public Dictionary<int,Component> Components{get;set;}
}

public class Component{
    public int Type{get;set;}
}

public class PositionComponent : Component{
    public Vector2 Location{get;set;}    
}
public class AreaComponent : Component{
    public Vector2 Offset{get;set;}
    public Rectangle Area{get;set;}   
}

static void Main{
    var entities = new Dictionary<Guid,Enity>();

    var e = new Entity();
    e.id = Guid.NewID();
    e.Components = new Dictionary<int,Component>{
            //Add a series of Components Here
        };

    entities.Add(e.ID,e);
}
```

now if i want to serialise this i'm not entirely sure where to start

i have tried defining each item as a DataContract i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class ComponentContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "t")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p")]
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Properties { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "Ent")]
public class EntityContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "comp")]
    public List<ComponentContract> Components { get; set; }
}
```

and adding a Generic ToContract() Method to Component

```
public class Component{
    public int Type{get;set;}

    public ComponentContract ToContract()
    {
        var c = new ComponentContract();
        c.Type = Type.ID;
        c.Properties = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        foreach (var v in this.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            c.Properties.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(v.Name, this.GetType().GetProperty(v.Name).GetValue(this, null).ToString()));
        }
        return c;

    }
}
```

however when i try to serialise this using DataContractSerialiser it is not returning much useful information

```
<ManagerContract xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Windows_Library.EntityComponentSystem.Managers" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Es xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Windows_Library.EntityComponentSystem.Entity">
    <a:Ent>
        <a:ccomp>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>1</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>2</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>3</t>
            </cc>
        </a:ccomp>
        <a:id>d047f8b6-cab0-4b04-81be-84a2380ef4f9</a:id>
        <a:type>MovingObject</a:type>
    </a:Ent>
    <a:Ent>
        <a:ccomp>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>1</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>2</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>3</t>
            </cc>
        </a:ccomp>
        <a:id>87f548cf-9292-4004-a492-d97f74ccd74b</a:id>
        <a:type>MovingObject</a:type>
    </a:Ent>
    <a:Ent>
        <a:ccomp>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>1</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>2</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>3</t>
            </cc>
        </a:ccomp>
        <a:id>8a08d24f-865e-4c08-a74f-5f6ed4add458</a:id>
        <a:type>MovingObject</a:type>
    </a:Ent>
    <a:Ent>
        <a:ccomp>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>1</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>2</t>
            </cc>
            <cc xmlns="">
                <p xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
                <t>3</t>
            </cc>
        </a:ccomp>
        <a:id>fd1c7d63-a1f7-46c4-87f0-8454bcb09600</a:id>
        <a:type>MovingObject</a:type>
    </a:Ent>
</Es>
</ManagerContract>
```

I realise i'm doing something wrong with the seriailsation of the Value of each property on the component, but also would you approach this issue in a different way? would i be better serialising to JSON? or somthing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own Question, I simply added a DataContract Flag to all relevant Classes and [DataMember] to all relevant properties

this required the use of [knowntype] flags for custom classes.

i then Serialised this using the DatacontractSerialiser and FileStream